# Webpack proxy inside docker throws EINVAL on connection to external local api

Tags: docker, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I have [quasar](https://quasar.dev) vue fronted which use web-pack dev server running inside docker and I use `proxy.js` (in main directory) to avoid CORS errors for API requests. However when I send request to API in my browser I see folowing error in terminal (where I run docker container):

> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request test.my-project.local:3081/auth/login to host.docker.internal:4000/akk [EINVAL] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

I use special docker value `host.docker.internal` for communication with backend (outside container) which is running in localhost:4000. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few hours on experiments, I reailsed that in `proxy.js` I have value

```js
target: "host.docker.internal:4000/akk",`
```

but shoud be

```js
target: "http://host.docker.internal:4000/akk",
```